# Create new array by matching values passed from html page

Tags: php, html, arrays, post

**EDIT:**

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

HTML page passes multiple characters through POST method. php grabs it and now 
depending on the vales passed from the HTML page, I want to create an fresh array by matching to an array items already there in php.

example: 
HTML passes these values to php 
`$_POST['a1'] | $_POST['a2'] | $_POST['a5'] | $_POST['a8']`

This is the fixed items array in php.
`$fixedItems = array(chair, cup, ladder, bed, pillow, shoes, apple, sprrrow);`

How do I create NEW array by matching the items passed from the HTML against the `$fixedItems` array.

```
if `$_POST['a1']` add "chair" to $fixedItems
if `$_POST['a2']` add "cup" to $fixedItems
if `$_POST['a3']` add "ladder" to $fixedItems 
if `$_POST['a4']` add "bed" to $fixedItems 
if `$_POST['a5']` add "pillow" to $fixedItems
```

so on...

Final result for the above example should be:

`$fixedItems = array("chair", "cup", "pillow");`

Comment: What do you mean by Fresh Array

Comment: Can we see the html? it may make it easier to work out what you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: So when `$_POST['a{n}']` `isset` you want to grab that specific element from the fixed list (`$fixedList[n-1]`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't completely understood what you are saying but you can use array_push() function in php to insert the data in an array.Use the code below

```
<?php
$fixedItems = array();
if (isset($_POST['a1'])){ array_push($fixedItems, "Chair");}
if (isset($_POST['a2'])){ array_push($fixedItems, "Cup"); }
if (isset($_POST['a3'])){ array_push($fixedItems, "Ladder"); }
if (isset($_POST['a4'])){ array_push($fixedItems, "bed"); }
if (isset($_POST['a5'])){ array_push($fixedItems, "Pillow"); }
?>
```

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to slightly change you `$fixedItems` array:

```
$fixedItems = array(
    'a1' => 'chair',
    'a2' => 'cup',
    'a3' => 'ladder',
    'a4' => 'bed',
    'a5' => 'pillow',
    'a6' => 'shoes',
    'a7' => 'apple',
    'a8' => 'sprrrow',
);

$freshArray = array();
foreach ($fixedItems as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($_POST[$key])) $freshArray[] = $value;
}
```

Depending on your needs you need to use `empty` in the above.

The above makes your code the easiest to expand if you need more posted elements in the future, because you can simply add another item to the array and it will automatically work.

Demo: https://eval.in/179698

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
// Create the array that will hold the matched data 
$newArray = array();
// Here are your matching conditions
$fixedItems = array('chair', 'cup', 'ladder', 'bed', 'pillow', 'shoes', 'apple', 'sprrrow');
// Loop through the info sent from the front-end
foreach($_POST AS $k => $v){
    // Check if the item posted is in the matching array
    if(in_array($k, $fixedItems)){
        // Add them to your new array, to build up your custom array of matched conditions.
        array_push($newArray, $v);
    }
}
```

Comment: Asking whether OP is looking for X or Y belongs in the comment section. Because when you guessed wrong your answer doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Yeah it was rhetorical question.. Didn't know humor doesn't belong in the answer section.

Comment: So you are saying you understand OPs needs?

Comment: very close to whatI'm looking for except `// Check if the item posted is in the matching array`. The front-end data does not match the items in `$fixedItems`.  I'm looking for something like `if($_POST['a1']){  array_push('chair');`  `if($_POST['a2']){  array_push('cup');` ... Hope that's clear.

Comment: Can you prove you understand anything by that logic?
I believe I understand his question yes.. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Well, then I'm wrong. I wasn't taking credit for being perfect.

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that you would like to build the $fixedItems array depending on which of the POST fields are set.

A way to achieve this is the array_push(); function of php

**Example:**

```
//Empty Array    
$fixedItems = array();

//Your if statement
if (isset($_POST['a1'])){
//Add it to the array
  array_push($fixedItems, "Chair");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you may try to use foreach to do create array automatically

```
  if (!empty( $_POST))
        {
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
            {
                $fixedItems = array_push($fixedItems, $_POST[$value]);
            }

        }
  return $fixedItems;
```